# Executable cannot be found

Tags: environment-variables, path

I installed gradle in `/opt/gradle-2.2.1`

I edited `/etc/environment` to look like this

```
GRADLE_HOME="/opt/gradle-2.2.1"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$GRADLE_HOME/bin"
```

If I run `source /etc/environment` gradle works as expected, but if I open a new terminal I keep getting this error message `The program 'gradle' is currently not installed` whenever I try to run gradle.

I trade to trace the problem by running  a couple of obvious things

```
$ echo $GRADLE_HOME 
/opt/gradle-2.2.1
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$GRADLE_HOME/bin
$ source /etc/environment
$ echo $PATH
 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/gradle-2.2.1/bin
```

You can see after running `source` the path is correct. I'm not sure why this is not resolving the first time around. Maybe the problem is that I don't understand what `/etc/environment` is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `/etc/environment` is read as-is, i.e. no parsing / evaluation / interpolation of variable is done. Put another way: it's not meant to be a shell script.

That is why the `$GRADLE_HOME` is literally there in your `PATH`.

You could simply replace the `$GRADLE_HOME` in your `PATH` definition with the actual value.